# Passing more than one parameter to another nsi

Tags: nsis

I have an installer I inherited, and I need to pass 2 parameters to another *.nsi on install. Currently it works fine with one param, which is just a string:

```
ExecShell "" '"$TEMP\Setup.exe"'    "Param1"
```

This gets read as so, from the other side:

```
${GetParameters} $commandLineParam
```

The second param is a variable ($version) that needs to be sent over:

```
StrCpy $version     "1.1.1.0"
```

Just adding an additional "Param2" doesn't build

> Error 13  error MSB3721: The command ""C:\Program Files (x86)\NSIS\Unicode\makensis" ... exited with code 1.

I'm sure I'm missing something syntax-wise.

Comment: That error is not coming from NSIS? MSBuild maybe? Posting the error from MakeNSIS would be more helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MakeNSIS removes the outer-most set of quotes when it parses the .NSI file.

```
StrCpy $0 "blah"
StrCpy $1 '"baz"'
ExecShell "" "c:\foo\bar.exe" 'p1 "Hello World" p3 $0 $1'
```

will run `c:\foo\bar.exe` with `p1 "Hello World" p3 blah "baz"` as the parameters.

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I needed. Thank you.

Comment: I'm aware that this might need to go into a different thread, but to extract this param from the other side, I suppose ${GetOptions} is the answer, but for some reason this is not building. I'm using the old Unicode NSIS (C:\Program Files (x86)\NSIS\Unicode), is it not supported?

Comment: You should ask a new question and post your code. And upgrade to the latest official NSIS.